# CSS 3 Div In Same Line - ! Fix With - Other two are percentage wise

Tags: css, view

I have three div's and I have set float left. So all are in now same line.

Div 01 -

Div 02 - Fix Width

Div 03 -

**Div 02 Should Be 300 px**. Other div should be same.

Ex :

If viewport is 1000px, Div 01 width=350px and Div 03 width=350px,

If viewport is 800px, Div 01 width=250px and Div 03 width=250px.

Is there way to do this without media quires? It is hard to write media queries for every viewpoints.

Comment: and where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way will be to use flexbox.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">left</div>
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
    <div class="flex-item">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
    background:red;
    flex: 1 auto;
}
.middle {
    background:blue;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/jennift/pen/vKBEwY

Answer (score 0):

So many ways. How about simply setting the widths explicitly.

```css
div {float:left}
div:nth-child(odd) {background:#EE9; width:calc(50% - 150px);}
div:nth-child(even) {background:#9EE; width:300px;}
```

```html
<div>left</div>
<div>middle</div>
<div>right</div>
```

Another way is to use a table.

```css
.table {display:table; border-spacing:0; width:100%}
.row {display:table-row}
.cell {display:table-cell}
.cell:nth-child(odd) {background:#EE9;}
.cell:nth-child(even) {background:#9EE; width:300px;}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">left</div>
    <div class="cell">middle</div>
    <div class="cell">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, flex boxes.

```css
.container {display:flex; width:100%; flex-basis:fill}
.container :nth-child(odd) {background:#EE9; flex-basis:fill; flex-grow:1}
.container :nth-child(even) {background:#9EE;  flex-basis:300px}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>middle</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```